# A weird issue with Change Capture stage

Tags: datastage, cdc

I design a parallel job with change capture, and my stage properties setting as follow:

```
exclude values: some fields I don't want to compare 
change keys: fields as keys 
options: 
change mode=Explicit Keys, All Values 
other settings as default.
```

[image]

I absolutely assure that I pick up the right fields as the keys, and I check the "key" option of these fields in the columns list. 
But when I run the job, I get the error:

> Change_Capture: A field cannot be both a key and a value.

[image]

**Here are the input and output columns:**
[image]
[image]

If I set

```
change mode= Explicit Keys & Values
```

and explicit the key fields and values fields, it works out.

How could that happen? I've spent nearly all day on that problem. Please help!

Comment: Can you share the input and output table definition? You speak about exculed fields but the picture just shows one. Is it a simplyfied job? Have you tried to reduce the number of value columns to check which one causes the error?

Comment: I've just added the columns settings. And I've tried to keep only one key and value fields, but didn't work

Answer (score 0):

Some options

1.Can you have the same field order for the change keys as present in your input steps.

Ex: In your change keys in CC stage SHEET_ID should come first before BARCODE.

2.Look for duplicate columns from both your inputs

Comment: 3. You can also remove the Key check in the Input Stages.

Comment: Thanks for replying. All your suggestions I've tried before, still no use. And I make sure there are no duplicate columns.

Comment: Can you disable Run Time column Propagation(RCP) in the transformtaion . Make sure you disable in Job properties and also in all stages

Comment: I remember facing this error because and it mostly because of Runtime Column Propagation. Please create a new job without RCP enabled( disable it in the job properties) and copy - paste the stages in the new job .

Answer (score 0):

As your requirement to use only set of keys, also exclude some value from the list of all the fields i.e. UPTIME (As you define)- You need to select Change mode as **'Explicit Keys & Values'**

For suppose you don't want to exclude UPTIME in your example -you can use Explicit Keys, all values, it works...

Comment: 'Explicit Keys & Values' would work. I've tried that. But I'm confused that I tried 'Explicit Keys, all values' and 'exclude values' in another job before, and it ran successfully.